# zsh doesn't work correctly in Mint

Tags: linux-mint, zsh

I successfully installed zsh, change config on my old, but it's not working properly.

I don't know how this feature calls. When i write something - `sudo` for instance, and press ↑ (arrow up) it doesn't searching line with this start text in history, it's just return previous line. [this is my zshrc file](https://gist.github.com/61d093fdccf50e9d6d2f)

Of course, the history contains expected lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me that you are referring to the [zsh-history-substring-search](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/history-substring-search) plugin. In which case, the first thing I noticed in your `.zshrc` is that you are not including that plugin in your list.

Change this line:

```
plugins=(git rvm rails3 bundler gem)
```

To:

```
plugins=(git rvm rails3 bundler gem history-substring-search)
```

Comment: Not working. Before Mint, in Kubuntu it works fine without that plugin.

Comment: Try adding `DEBIAN_PREVENT_KEYBOARD_CHANGES=yes` to your `~/.zshenv`. Refer to this issue: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1433

Comment: No problem. Glad it works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux Mint Debian Edition (LMDE), then add these lines to your `~/.zshrc`:

```sh
# keybindings for history autocomplete
[[ -n "${key[Up]}" ]] && bindkey "${key[Up]}" history-beginning-search-backward
[[ -n "${key[Down]}" ]] && bindkey "${key[Down]}" history-beginning-search-forward
```

It works *better* than the plugin because the plugin requires typing at least 3 chars, while the keybindings start working at the first char typed.